# JS + Lodash Filter an object on the basis of the value of a prop

Tags: javascript, lodash, ramda.js

I'm pretty new to JS and using lodash for a project. Here I have an object of objects and I need to filter out the objects according to the value of a prop. I've gone through some other stack overflow post but did not able to get the required output :

My object is as follows :

```
var parameters = {
  "param_a": {
    "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", 
    "description": "Description of the Parameter A", 
    "status": "absolute",
  }, 
  "param_b": {
    "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", 
    "description": "Description of the Parameter B", 
    "status": "absolute",
  },
  "param_c": {
    "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", 
    "description": "Description of the Parameter C", 
    "status": "relative",
  }, 
}
```

I need to get separate objects according to a status like :

```
var absolute_parameters = {
  "param_a": {
    "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", 
    "description": "Description of the Parameter A", 
    "status": "absolute",
  }, 
  "param_b": {
    "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", 
    "description": "Description of the Parameter B", 
    "status": "absolute",
  },
}

var relative_parameters = {
  "param_c": {
    "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", 
    "description": "Description of the Parameter C", 
    "status": "relative",
  },
}
```

I've tried this but it returns the original object as it is :

```
 relative_parameters = _.pickBy(parameters, function(value, key) {return 'relative';})
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've updated the question, with my attempt. Thank you !!

Comment: "*My object is as follows*", no, objects can only have one same key in strict mode and in sloppy mode, the last overwrites the earlier keys.

Comment: @NinaScholz It was a typo, I've edited my question. Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with lodash via [`entries`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#toPairs) + [`filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#filter) + [`fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#fromPairs):

```js
var parameters = { "param_a": { "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", "description": "Description of the Parameter A", "status": "absolute", }, "param_b": { "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", "description": "Description of the Parameter B", "status": "absolute", }, "param_c": { "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", "description": "Description of the Parameter C", "status": "relative", }, }

const getByStatus = (s) => _(parameters).entries()
  .filter(([k,{status}]) => _.isEqual(status,s)).fromPairs().value()

console.log(getByStatus('absolute'))
console.log(getByStatus('relative'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With ES6 you could use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) + [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var parameters = { "param_a": { "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", "description": "Description of the Parameter A", "status": "absolute", }, "param_b": { "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", "description": "Description of the Parameter B", "status": "absolute", }, "param_c": { "created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", "description": "Description of the Parameter C", "status": "relative", }, }

const getByStatus = (s) => Object.entries(parameters)
   .filter(([k,{status}]) => status == s).reduce((r,[k,v]) => (r[k]=v,r),{})

console.log(getByStatus('absolute'))
console.log(getByStatus('relative'))
```

Comment: `groupBy` takes only the inner objects.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript, you could take an object as result set and assign the objects to the wanted group of `status`

```js
var data = { param_a: { created: "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", description: "Description of the Parameter A", status: "absolute" }, param_b: { created: "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", description: "Description of the Parameter B", status: "absolute" }, param_c: { created: "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", description: "Description of the Parameter C", status: "relative" } },
    absolute_parameters = {},
    relative_parameters = {};

Object
    .entries(data)
    .reduce(
        (r, [k, o]) => (Object.assign(r[o.status], { [k]: o }), r),
        { absolute: absolute_parameters, relative: relative_parameters }
    );

console.log(absolute_parameters);
console.log(relative_parameters);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this [tagged Ramda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ramda.js).  If a Ramda answer is acceptable (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author), you could do something like this:

```js
const parameters = {"param_a": {"created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", "description": "Description of the Parameter A", "status": "absolute"}, "param_b": {"created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", "description": "Description of the Parameter B", "status": "absolute"}, "param_c": {"created": "2018-10-08T05:14:19.498Z", "description": "Description of the Parameter C", "status": "relative"}}

const [absolute_parameters, relative_parameters] = 
    R.partition(R.propEq('status', 'absolute'), parameters)

console.log(absolute_parameters)
console.log(relative_parameters)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

This depends upon your `status` field always having one of these two values.  You could also create them independently, using [`filter`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter) instead of [`partition`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#partition), at the cost of looping twice:

```
const absolute_parameters = R.filter(R.propEq('status', 'absolute'), parameters)
const relative_parameters = R.filter(R.propEq('status', 'relative'), parameters)
```